# MP3 reader (creative Zen) no more mounted after Raring upgrade

Tags: usb, 13.04

Since I did the upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04, my creative Zen mp3 player is no more seen by Ubuntu. It is not mounted at all. However, it is correctly displayed by the `lsusb` command.
What should I do ?

Comment: Check output from `lsusb`. Is the device listed? What is the brand/model id? eg. **34f5:4e41**

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Here is the output of the lsusb command: it looks like the device is recognized (bus 3, device 004)    

Bus 003 Device 004: ID 041e:4155 Creative Technology, Ltd Zen Stone plus       Is there something I can do to have it automatically mounted ?

Comment: Are you using some software app. to store/manage your music? Does this see / interface to music player (MP3 device)? *Or, do you just want to mount the device, and copy files to.from it?*

Comment: I do not use software, I just want to mount it and copy files to/from it. But no way to mount it.  Thanks

Comment: I tried again using gnomad, and sudo gnomad, but in both cases, it says it can not detect the player. Any help please ?